# Contents in an ArrayList get modified

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem on a program I'm making that I honestly can't find a solution for. It seems the objects contained on a Java ArrayList collection are being modified without me programming such modifications.

The program as a whole is meant to basically create a random connection between two nodes on a 10x10 grid by moving through a path. This path is represented as an ArrayList collection of points in the grid, with the first index containing the first node's location (node A) and the last index containing the second node's location (node B). How I do this is by locating myself on A's location, and then moving randomly to contiguous points in the grid, repeating this in a while loop until B's location is reached.

Everything seems to work except that the "path" collection is altered somehow, such that every point in it ends up being the same as the last point to which I move, which is also B's location.

The method is as follows:

```
public void generateRandomPath()
{
    path = new ArrayList<Point>();
    path.add(pInitial);
    complete = false;

    while(!complete)
    {
        k = path.get(path.size()-1);
        d = selectDirection(k);

        GUI.log.append("==== Before the method. ==== \n");
        GUI.log.append(Integer.toString(path.get(path.size()-1).getX())+" - "+Integer.toString(path.get(path.size()-1).getY())+"\n");

        x = move(k, d);
        path.add(x);

        if(k.getX() == pEnd.getX() && k.getY() == pEnd.getY())
            complete = true;

    }
    GUI.log.append("Finished. \n");
}
```

- "**Point**" are simply points, with an X
  and Y coordinate represented by
  integers.
- "**pInitial**" is the point representing the location of node A.
- "**pEnd**" is the point representing the location of node B.
- "**d**" is the direction on which I'm going to move on this repetition. This can be either up, right, down, or left represented by an integer 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively.
- "**k**" is the last point in the path, which is the point to which it moved on the previous repetition.
- "**x**" is the new point to which it moved on the current repetition.

So what it basically does is it grabs the last point in the path as reference, chooses a direction, and then moves to the point contiguous on that direction. Each repetition of the while loop should add a new **point** to **path**. However what ends up happening is that not only is this new point added, but every other **point** already in **path** takes the value of this last point added. By utilizing the log entries show above (GUI.log.append) I managed to see that **path** is being mysteriously altered inside the step:

```
x = move(k, d);
```

Which is the following method:

```
private Point move(Point n, int y)
{
    GUI.log.append("==== Inside the method. ==== \n");
    GUI.log.append(Integer.toString(path.get(path.size()-1).getX())+" - "+Integer.toString(path.get(path.size()-1).getY())+"\n");

    Point newP = n;
    if(y == 1)
        newP.setY(n.getY()-1);
    if(y == 2)
        newP.setX(n.getX()+1);
    if(y == 3)
        newP.setY(n.getY()+1);
    if(y == 4)
        newP.setX(n.getX()-1);

    GUI.log.append("==== After method. ==== \n");
    GUI.log.append(Integer.toString(path.get(path.size()-1).getX())+" - "+Integer.toString(path.get(path.size()-1).getY())+"\n");

    return newP;
}
```

Integer **y** is the direction as mentioned before. As you can see this method does not alter **path** in any way, yet the logs show it does. In this example node A was on the **point** X = 2, Y = 3. The log shows what the coordinates of the last **point** in **path** are. As you can see, the coordinates of the last point in **path** take on the value of the coordinates of the new **point**, but this new **point** was not yet added to **path**.

[image: Example of the alteration of path.]

I honestly don't know how this is happening. If anyone could think of a reason I would appreciate it very much if you could tell me.

Comment: Suggestion - when you put code snippets for inspection, remove all logging statements out. Leave only the bare-bones algorithm which is basically what you want people to inspect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
Point newP = new Point(n.getX(), n.getY());
```

instead of

```
 Point newP = n;
```

Comment: or Point newP = (Point)p.clone();

Comment: @MBFT - Assuming Point is a Cloneable. Otherwise, that's a good way to get a kaput moment.

Comment: That solved it! I can't thank you enough, it probably never would've occurred to me. Thanks!

Comment: or `Point newP = new Point(n);`

Comment: @luis of course Point is cloneable :) wouldn't have suggested if it wasn't.

Comment: @Hans - it's an easy mistake to make, specially when burning midnight oil. One thing I've seen done to prevent such errors is to to have `Point` implement an interface that only has `getters` (no `setters`), and you pass that interface to method arguments. That can get into a kludge pretty fast, though. This is one of the cases were I miss the C++ feature of **constantifying** both references (or pointers) and the objects they refer/point to. Never understood why Gosling left that one out from Java. Oh well.

Comment: @MBFG - do we know whether 'Point' in this examle is indeed a 'java.awt.Point' (which is cloneable) or just a class that happened to be called 'Point'? ;)

Comment: @Luis Thanks a lot for the help, I see what you're saying. Point is actually a class I made :P